# Making a python standalone Linux executable on windows

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, server, executable

I have a python server application that I wish to put onto my server. I have tried to run the python scripts on my server, I moved the file with sftp and I installed the dependancies with pip. No luck, it doesn't use my modules even after I install them. It says the module I installed isn't a thing, when when I run pip again it says it is already there. I read about standalone executables a little, but I only found documentation on windows ones. I know Linux cannot run exe files, but is there something similar.

Another thing might be my unfamiliarity with pip. I use the terminal in py charm which automatically puts my pip modules into files. When I do that on my ubuntu machines there is no file created in my directory. (Feels like a problem to me)

Comment: Always use `python -m pip` to make sure the python and the pip agree with each other.

Comment: I am pretty sure I did -m for everything. I'll ssh back in a few after dinner and go for it again thanks a lot though anything helps.

Comment: Try using something like [Pipenv](https://pipenv.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) to setup an environment for you. Make sure it works on your linux box first and then in theory you should just be able to `pipenv install && pipenv run python blah.py` from your windows box.

Comment: Is your problem that you have a Linux HTTP server (Apache, etc) and wish to run Python scripts from the browser? You need, I think, the scripts installed in the context of the `apache` user, so perhaps this question would be better on [Server Fault](https://serverfault.com).

Comment: @KenY-N No i dont have a http client I need to access. I made a discord bot for my discord server is all. For some reason though I can't get the python files to make the switch from windows to Linux.

Comment: What error do you see when you run the scripts? Python scripts should have the extension `.py`, so I'm not sure why you mention `.exe`.

Comment: @KenY-N I mentioned exe because that's an executable I didnt want any confusion. I get "ImportError: No module named 'discord.ext'; 'discord' is not a package

Comment: Please add that error message to the question so everyone can see it. BTW, have you seen [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51535001/1270789)? Python 3.7 doesn't play well with Discord, it seems.

Comment: Yep I know that I am running 3.5 on my server right now. Not sure what to do. I checked the python install directories and there isnt anything there about discord.

Comment: Of course Linux systems have binary executables, but building your modules into an executable is likely to be much more complicated than just fixing the installation you have.

Comment: @DavisHerring What would you recommend I do to fix it? My next bet is to redo my whole server. It has nothing important i guess.

Comment: @Hunter: You just have to resolve the contradiction that it’s installed but not found.  Obviously something is misconfigured; there’s not nearly enough information here to determine what (and that’s for Super User or Server Fault anyway).

Comment: if you run `python -m pip install <something>`, it is installed under the current user (Typically ~/.local/). If your application is run under a different user, the installed package will not be found. You can install with `sudo -H python -m pip install <something>` to make it available to all users.

Comment: @JohnAnderson I looked up where they install to by default, but for some reason it does not work. I had a great idea though. I'm going to install gnome. Then install my ide(just like my development laptop) then I'll bring over the project and stuff, using my ide cuz it handels pip in its own command line. Then I'll disable the gui and bam back to server, but still runnable from the command line. I know its more of a bandaid, but i gotta do something soon.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I don't want to leave this open in case anyone else see this and needs help. I had forgotten to install my modules, so I did that, and then to run my two programs I just use screen now to host different terminals for each program. It isn't very hard.